# SublimeText3 double-backslash in snippet

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text, escaping, snippets

I'm using SublimeText3 with LaTeXTools for my LaTeX work and want it to insert a double-backslash+newline when I hit ctrl+enter. Like this:

```
asdf\\
foobar
```

I tried inserting the following into "Default (Linux).sublime-keymap":

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+enter"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {"contents": "\\\\\n"},
    "context":
        [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"}
        ]
}
```

But what it creates on ctrl+enter is:

```
asdf\
foobar
```

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try adding more backslashes to "contents"? :)

Comment: oh damn it. just too simple. why didn't I come up with this? thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution (thanks to Karan):

Insert into "Default (Linux).sublime-keymap":

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+enter"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {"contents": "\\\\\\\\\n"},
    "context":
        [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"}
        ]
}
```